# Pandas Dataframe: Operations on columns without iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Despite the confusing title my problem is simple: I have a DataFrame with the coordinates of several bodies and want to calculate their distance without having to run on every row. My DataFrame is called S and looks like

```
                   X        Y
   id
4000000030992760  542478  175110
4000000030146750  538252  175394
4000000030237400  536188  176897
4000000030099730  536496  174693
4000000030418980  529663  181684
4000000030238500  532567  179727
4000000030146350  535936  173268
4000000030146220  535051  173088
4000000030709450  539079  173084
4000000031197690  522850  178571
```

I would like to calculate the distance of every segment from every other. For the moment I am doing like this

```
for ind1,j in S.iterrows():
    for ind2,k in S.iterrows():
        d = math.sqrt((j.x-k.x)**2+(j.y-k.y)**2)
```

but I am sure there is a more efficient way of proceding.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to build a distance matrix ?
If so you can use an already written function from [`scipy`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html) or [`sklearn`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#sklearn-metrics-metrics) like:

```
from scipy.spatial import distance_matrix
loc = df[['X','Y']].values
dist_mat = distance_matrix(loc, loc)

from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
dist_mat = cdist(loc, loc)
```

More generally speaking, what you are looking for is the *vectorized* property of the columns of your `DataFrame`. You can use already vectorized functions (like *numpy* ones) and operators. If not, you can use the `apply` method (or `applymap`) to apply a function to a columns (or your rows) without iterating on it ([pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#applying-elementwise-python-functions) about that).

An efficient numpy way to calculate the distance between all your locations could be :

```
def make_dist_mat(xy):
    d0 = np.subtract.outer(xy[:,0], xy[:,0])
    d1 = np.subtract.outer(xy[:,1], xy[:,1])
    return np.hypot(d0, d1)

make_dist_mat(df[['X', 'Y']].astype(float).values)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks for the answer.